# PHP PDO with BindValue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindvalue

I found some problem about bindvalue and can't find a solution. 
this is my code it are work great if in put email like this "abc@aaamail.com" but my problem is when user are input email like "abc.def@aaamail.com" this query it not work. I don't know why and how to fix it anybody can explain to me?

```
$email  = trim($_POST['email']);
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `memberlist` WHERE email = :email");
$result->bindValue(':email', $email);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: The difference being… that there’s a dot?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single problem about bindValue. It works with any data.

> anybody can explain to me?

Just make sure it's indeed bindValue *or any other code* to blame. Then fix that other code.